# Pure CSS horizontal scroll issue

Tags: css

I am trying to pile up divs horizontally within a horizontal-scroll-only parent div but for some reason the child divs refuse to do so. Works fine if I add content only (text or images) in the `content-wrapper` but if as soon as I add divs things fall apart.

All help highly appreciated

**THE CSS**

```
.wrapper {
background: #000000;
margin: auto;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100% !important;
}

.left-bar {
left: 0;
top: 0;
min-height: 100%;
width: 200px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 2;
margin: 0;
background-color: #999;
}

.top-bar {
top: 0;
min-width: 100%;
height: 150px;
position: fixed;
margin: 0;
margin-left: 200px;
background-color: #0F0;
}

.content-wrapper {
left: 200px;
margin-top: 150px;
min-height: 100%;
background-color: #06F;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden !important;
white-space: nowrap;
position: absolute;
}

.content-column {
width: 250px;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
margin-right: 20px;
background-color: #F00;
float: left;
text-align: center;
}
```

**THE HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="left-bar">LEFT BAR</div>
<div class="top-bar">TOP BAR</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-column">TEXT<br /><img src="http://placehold.it/250x450" /><br />MORE TEXT</div>
    <div class="content-column">TEXT<br /><img src="http://placehold.it/250x450" /><br />MORE TEXT</div>
    <div class="content-column">TEXT<br /><img src="http://placehold.it/250x450" /><br />MORE TEXT</div>
    <div class="content-column">TEXT<br /><img src="http://placehold.it/250x450" /><br />MORE TEXT</div>
    <div class="content-column">TEXT<br /><img src="http://placehold.it/250x450" /><br />MORE TEXT</div>
    <div class="content-column">TEXT<br /><img src="http://placehold.it/250x450" /><br />MORE TEXT</div>
    <div class="content-column">TEXT<br /><img src="http://placehold.it/250x450" /><br />MORE TEXT</div>
</div><!-- end content wrapper -->
</div><!-- end wrapper -->
```

**CONTENT ONLY / WORKING FIDDLE**
<kbd>**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/TSGq7/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `div` either `display:inline` or `display:inline-block`

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/Re3Ld/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div>bleh</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x450" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x450" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x450" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x450" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x450" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x450" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x450" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x450" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x450" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content-wrapper > div {
  display:inline-block;   
}
```

Comment: looks good when using only "<div>CONTENT</div>" but if I add ".content-wrapper > .content-column" the same problem prevails

Comment: had to remove the "float:left" from ".content-column".. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Give ".content-wrapper" a width.

```
.content-wrapper {
    left: 200px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #06F;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
}
```